# 'super' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, django-templates

models.py

here is the manager class

```
class ProductAttributeManager(models.Manager):
    def all(self):
        return super(ProductAttributeManager , self)
    def type(self):
        return self.all().filter(name__icontains='type')
    def fabric(self):
        return self.all().filter(name__icontains='fabric')
```

here is the model

```
class ProductAttribute(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Value = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    objects = ProductAttributeManager()
```

here is the template where i have used the productattribute set to get the attribute name and value and getting the error while calling it

```
{% for attribute in product.productattribute_set.all %}
<tr><td><strong>{{ attribute.name }}</strong></td><td>{{ attribute.Value }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

and here is the traceback

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  164.                 response = response.render()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  158.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  135.         content = template.render(context, self._request)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  74.         return self.template.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  209.                     return self._render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  201.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  135.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  201.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  65.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  161.                 values = list(values)

Exception Type: TypeError at /products/3/
Exception Value: 'super' object is not iterable
```

first time i have encountered this problem.
Why is the super object not iterable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `all()` method should return a queryset. For example, you could do

```
class ProductAttributeManager(models.Manager):
    def all(self):
        return super(ProductAttributeManager , self).all()
```

However, the above method does not actually change the behaviour, so you could just remove the `all()` method instead.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this would work if you were overriding `QuerySet` methods and then getting a manager with `as_manager()`. The whole copying of methods thing might be confusing at first time.

Comment: i didnt get you on this one @Ivan